# about orange3, exe file is not worked with an pyimod02_importers error

Tags: orange

pip install orange3

main.py
import Orange

pyinstaller main.py

main.exe was made... but when executed, there is an pyimod02_importers error.

main.py works well in pycham...

but main.exe don't work...

how can it be solved?